# Plotly data display issue in Angular

Tags: angular, plotly

Currently, vertical line is drawn where the first part of pie ends. Due to this,it is overwriting the heading and in cases, text is hidden. Need to display the vertical line in bottom in all cases.

[image]

Below is my component

```
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    AfterViewInit,
    NgZone,
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    OnChanges,
    Output,
    EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

declare var Plotly: any;

/**
 * Custom typing for plotly
 * TODO :: Use provided .d.ts
 */
export interface IPlotLayout {
    title: string;
    autosize: boolean;
    showlegend: boolean;
    separators: string;
    hidesources: boolean;
    xaxis: any;
    yaxis: any;
    yaxis2: any;
    margin: any;
    height: number;
    width: number;
    hovermode: 'closest' | 'x' | 'y' | false;
    hoverlabel: any;
    direction: 'clockwise' | 'counterclockwise';
    orientation: 'v' | 'h';
    legend: any;
    font: any;
    barmode: string;
    annotations: any;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'plot',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div id="chart{{ id }}"></div>
        </div>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PlotlyComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() data: any[];
    @Input() layout: Partial<IPlotLayout>;
    @Input() options: any;
    @Input() id: string = '';
    @Input() style: {} = {};
    //is the view initialized for plotly.js to take action
    viewInitialized: boolean = false;
    @Input() downloadCSV: boolean = false;
    @Output() exportToCSV = new EventEmitter();

    _container;

    constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let d3 = Plotly.d3,
            WIDTH_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT = 95,
            HEIGHT_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT = 95;
        let style = {
            width: WIDTH_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT + '%',
            'margin-left': (100 - WIDTH_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT) / 2 + '%',

            height: HEIGHT_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT + 'vh',
            'margin-top': (100 - HEIGHT_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT) / 2 + 'vh'
        };
        if (Object.keys(this.style).length > 0) {
            style = { ...style, ...this.style };
        }
        let gd3 = d3
            .select(`#chart${this.id}`)
            .append('div')
            .style(style);
        this._container = gd3.node();

        /**
         * On the first run, plot the graph after view has been initialized('div' exists)
         * After that, all subsequent plot changes should be handled by OnChanges hook
         */
        this.update();
        this.viewInitialized = true;
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.viewInitialized) {
            this.update();
        }
    }

    update() {
        /**
         * Plot the graph outside change detection
         * TODO :: Investigate bubbling up chart events for future scaling
         * TODO :: Try adding animations on update...
         */
        let self = this;
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            self.appendCustomExport();
            Plotly.newPlot(
                self._container,
                self.data,
                self.layout,
                self.options
            );
        });
    }
}
```

The data is dynamic and pie may contain one or more sections

Another case

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpPGT.png)

Comment: please put your code to question too

Comment: added. Please check

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you work on you chart size first.

In any case, if your pie chart is same size as your container, it will always create problems showing legends and other information on hover. So make your pie chart smaller. Your pie radius should not be more than 40% of your container's height.

To avoid sorting by plotly, pass in the following to your data array:

```
data: [sort:false]
```

I hope it will let you achieve your expected layout.